# Can't measure Clientwidth of Html-Image in Firefox

Tags: html, vb.net, firefox, web-applications, image-size

I am trying to place markers on points of interest (poi) on an Image.
These poi have been set in a different software and were stored in a database. The position is determined by their pixel position relative to the original Image. In my webapp the Images are scaled down thanks to panzoom.js (a plugin irrelevant to my question I think). I got the right formula to scale the markerposition, the only Problem is:
In firefox I'm unable to read the Images size in time (In Chrome that's not an Issue).
This is the Code

```
$(document).ready(function ()
    {
        var imagectrl = document.getElementById('<%= img.ClientID %>');
        var hiddenfield = document.getElementById('<%= hf.ClientID %>');

        if (hiddenfield.value == "")
        {
            var myWidth;
            var myHeight;
            myWidth = imagectrl.clientWidth;
            myHeight = imagectrl.clientHeight;

            hiddenfield.value = myWidth + ';' + myHeight;
            __doPostBack();
        }
    });
```

If I do a postback manually (clicking a button that shows the Image in higher quality) the size gets written correctly.

I've also tried calling an identical function from Code behind when my X or Y are 0, but nothing worked.

What can i do to get the Images size when first loading the page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a Solution:
No matter what I did, the Image itself can't be measured in time.
So i gave the Image the height of it's surrounding control via CSS and used

```
AddHandler dvGalerieFill.Load, AddressOf Me.measure_height
```

in the Page_Load method to react to the loading of the surrounding control.
In "measure_height" I called my Javascript function.
Through the height of the control (wich is the height of my image)
I can calculate the width of my image as height and width rescale with the same factor.

Answer (score 0):

Firefox has a different implementation on *asynchronous operations* like image loading than Chrome. I guess this could be the reason why in Chrome you can access the image right away with `$(document).ready`, but in Firefox the image source gets loaded *after* the document is ready - thus `clientWidth` and `clientHeight` will be undefined.

**Solution:** Define an [onload event handler](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/Attribute/image.onload) on your image and put your logic into that method:

```
$(document).ready(function ()
{
    var imagectrl = document.getElementById('<%= img.ClientID %>');
    var hiddenfield = document.getElementById('<%= hf.ClientID %>');

    imagectrl.onload = function() {
        if (hiddenfield.value == "")
        {
            var myWidth;
            var myHeight;
            myWidth = imagectrl.clientWidth;
            myHeight = imagectrl.clientHeight;

            hiddenfield.value = myWidth + ';' + myHeight;
            __doPostBack();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work. I tried adding "onload" to the Image (with a Javascript function as the handler) and I wrote an Event Handler in the Code Behind. Neither option resulted the right outcome